# How to add filter and paging to WpfToolkit datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I want to add filter to columns in [WPFToolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) datagrid. Is it possible to make it work like the ones in commercial grids *(like in DevExpress's or Telerik's..)*? Also a small second question about paging in datagrid..Do i need the one in the grid *(i just want fast grid, so i thought about paging. Or maybe data virtualization there works just fine?)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ICollectionView.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter.aspx) property.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_datagrid_filter.aspx) demonstrates its use.

EDIT: I've used Virtualization with a list view with some 100k entries without any performance issues. I haven't used it in a data grid. I guess it really depends on how many rows you are planning on displaying and how you plan to allow or force the user to narrow the criteria. Those are business decisions on your (or your Boss') part though.

Comment: Also found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx . Thank you. And what about paging? do we need it in simple WPF grid(but with filters)?